# What will happen if I restore backup DB with empty session table?

Tags: 6, database, sessions, backups

It seems that only the session is really big compared with other tables.
Is there any bad effect to Drupal site if I restore my backup Mysql file after deleting all the rows in session table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that people will need to log in again.

A side effect of this is that any session data that your site may have saved for users will also be gone.  This is usually a nuisance, and not a major problem, though.

Personally, I have never had any problems caused by either not restoring `{sessions}` or manually clearing out the table, either via `DELETE FROM {sessions}` or a [drush command](http://drupal.org/node/1611952).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I don't have to be worried about his huge session table any more.